# How to set up store date

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I have data I would like to use in multiple components and manipulate. For that reason I decided to start using store, but I don't know at what stage I'm supposed to do request to the server and set store data.

The question is probably asked before but I could not find it

Comment: You need to provide more information to this question.

Comment: Well, it's straight forward, to be honest, let's say I have users, I would like to access users in actions component as well where I would like to edit/delete user data. I need to have users in the store so I can access it in all other components, previously I used to load user data in the allUsers component, now that I will be putting it up on the store, I probably need to load data in somewhere else,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clearly but if you want to centralize your logic. Your store file looks like that:

```
state:{
   user:{
      id: "",
      name: "",
      ...
      ..
      .
   }
}

getters:{
   get_user: state => state.user,
   get_userID: state => state.user.id,
   ...
}

mutations:{
   SET_USER(state, payload){
      state.user = payload
   },
   SET_USER_ID(state, payload){
      state.user.id = payload
   }
   ...
}

actions:{
   add_user({ commit }, userData){
      // you can make some http request here if you have
      commit("SET_USER", userData)
   }
}
```

Basically, above code is showing you a logic. If you want to get some data which is in state, you should had a getters. If you want to change some data which is in state, you should use mutations to make this. If you want to make some functionality like post user detail to server, fetching data from server something like this you should use actions and even you can make those changes in your actions, don't. Because actions work async, mutations not.

I hope this is answer what you looking for.